Query all channels with unread messages by an specific user in StreamChat sdk for iOS app
https://getstream.io/chat/docs/ios-swift/query_channels/
In above link have option to filter and sort based on options they provide.
But not able to create query to only get channel list only having unread messages.
#StreamChat
